# Exclude label tags with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is label.

```
<label style="vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer;">Terrain</label>
```

It is nested in following structure (see label at the end):

```
<div class="event-section">
   <div class="googlemaps">
     <div id="googleMap6512">
        <div>
           <div class="gm-style">
              <div class="gmnoprint">
                <div class="gm-style-mtc">
                   <div>
                      <div>
                        <label>...
```

Problem:
I want to exclude this label in my Javascript together with the label from another `div.widget_small` and I tried this here:

```
var arrInp = document.querySelectorAll("label:not(.googlemaps):not(.widget_small)");
```

This did not work. I think I picked the wrong selector or… ?

Comment: Can you show a representative example of your HTML, because without that it's impossible to answer your question without making guesses.

Comment: what is expected and current behaviour?

Comment: @ChrisLi - I cannot grab the right selector for the `label` to input in my js. A double ´not` also does not seem correct. Its a syntax issue.

Comment: you want to ignore label under .googlemaps and .widget_small? maybe querySelector("div:not(.googlemaps):not(.widget_small) label) ?

Answer (score 2):

Classes are not inherited.

The `label` isn't a member of `googlemaps` or `widget_small` so `label:not(.googlemaps):not(.widget_small)` does match it.

You need to select a label where *none of the ancestors* are members of those classes.

There is no way to express that in a selector, so you need to select all `label` elements and then loop over them filtering out those which have ancestors with either of those classes (which you can determine by recursively looping over `.parentNode` until you find one which matches `.googlemaps, .widget_small` (fail) or `body` (success).

Alternatively, you can might be able to be very precise about which ancestors the element has:

```
:not(.googlemaps) > * > * > * > * > * > * > * > label
```

… but that is probably more trouble to maintain than it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
var arrInp = document.querySelectorAll("label:not(.googlemaps):not(.widget_small)");
```

the selector part gets all `label` which haven't the classes `.googlemaps` or `.widget_small` .

Please see reference to the :not selector: [MDN web docs :not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

To achieve a solution consider @Quentin's statement.

**Update**

Maybe sth. like this is what you need, like @ChrisLi mentioned above?

```
var arrInp = document.querySelectorAll(".event-section > div:not(.googlemaps):not(.widget_small) label");
```

Comment: correct, I want to grab all `label` except the ´label` from `googlemaps` and `widget_small` div classes.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple approach, using JavaScript, is the following:

```js
// converting the resulting iterable into an Array:
Array.from(
  // using document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve
  // a NodeList of all <label> elements in the
  // document:
  document.querySelectorAll('label')

  // filtering that Array of <label> elements with
  // Array.prototype.filter():
).filter(
  // using an Arrow function to filter the Array elements:
  // 'el' is a reference to the current Array element,
  // here we find the closest ancestor element which
  // matches the supplied selector; coupled with the NOT
  // (!) operator to invert the 'truthiness' of the result,
  // therefore if closest() returns null (no element was
  // found) we convert that to true; thereby keeping the
  // Array elements with no matching ancestors:
  (el) => !el.closest('.demo, .test')

  // iterating over the resulting Array using
  // Array.prototype.forEach():
).forEach(
  // with another Arrow function, here we use the
  // Element.classList API to add a class, in this
  // instance just to demonstrate which element(s)
  // were found:
  (label) => label.classList.add('orange')
);
```

```css
.orange {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"><label for="">label 1<input type="text"></label></div>
<div class="test"><label for="">label 1<input type="text"></label></div>
<label for="">label 1<input type="text"></label>
```

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Arrow.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [Logical NOT (`!`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!)).